# .htaccess allow access from local and allow access from external just one subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i am trying in my .htaccess to allow access only from local network to all site and allow access from external network just one subfolder to read some php

docroot - var/wwww/html

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com\:8080$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

var/www/html/site

.htaccess

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 172.16.1.*
```

var/www/html/site/public

.htaccess

```
allow from all
```

from lan, docroot and all site is ok

from external, docroot is ok but site and public folder i get "Internal Server Error"

could you help me how to solve this problem?
thanks!!

ps: sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `"Internal Server Error"` because your `RewriteCond` is wrong and your rules are constantly looping.

This condition is the problem:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com\:8080$
```

Since `%{HTTP_HOST}` only matches host name **without port number**.

You can have it this way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com$
```